# Can I chain multiple actions for every item in a repeat list

Tags: azure-logic-apps

tried a simple logic app where I was able to retrieve a list from an API. Using the repeat over a list feature, I was able to send an email for every item in the list.

But I really want to be able to perform several chained actions/steps for every item in the list...isn't that possible? I know I can have multiple actions/steps that perform something for each item in the same list...but these are not chained as in the following code:

```
    "triggers": {
    "recurrence": {
        "recurrence": {
            "frequency": "Day",
            "interval": 1
        },
        "type": "Recurrence"
    }
},
"actions": {
    "http": {
        "type": "Http",
        "inputs": {
            "method": "GET",
            "uri": "https://example.com/pcme/3/7",
            "headers": {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Basic my auth"
            }
        },
        "conditions": []
    },
    "office365connector": {
        "type": "ApiApp",
        "inputs": {
            "apiVersion": "2015-01-14",
            "host": {
                "id": "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourcegroups/workflows/providers/Microsoft.AppService/apiapps/office365connector",
                "gateway": "https://workflowsxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net"
            },
            "operation": "SendMail",
            "parameters": {
                "message": {
                    "To": "some-email@me.com",
                    "Subject": "@repeatItem().activationCode"
                }
            },
            "authentication": {
                "type": "Raw",
                "scheme": "Zumo",
                "parameter": "@parameters('/subscriptions/xxxxxx/resourcegroups/workflows/providers/Microsoft.AppService/apiapps/office365connector/token')"
            }
        },
        "repeat": "@body('http')",
        "conditions": [
            {
                "expression": "@equals(actions('http').status, 'Succeeded')"
            }
        ]
    },
    "office365connector0": {
        "type": "ApiApp",
        "inputs": {
            "apiVersion": "2015-01-14",
            "host": {
                "id": "/subscriptions/xxxx/resourcegroups/workflows/providers/Microsoft.AppService/apiapps/office365connector",
                "gateway": "https://workflowsdxxxx.azurewebsites.net"
            },
            "operation": "SendMail",
            "parameters": {
                "message": {
                    "To": "some-email@gmail.com",
                    "Subject": "@repeatItem().cardNumber"
                }
            },
            "authentication": {
                "type": "Raw",
                "scheme": "Zumo",
                "parameter": "@parameters('/subscriptions/xxxxx/resourcegroups/workflows/providers/Microsoft.AppService/apiapps/office365connector/token')"
            }
        },
        "repeat": "@body('http')",
        "conditions": [
            {
                "expression": "@equals(actions('http').status, 'Succeeded')"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Thank you for any help.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

One option for chaining actions over each item in the list is to use a nested logic app.

The way you would set it up is to have a child logic app with a chain of actions that you want to apply to each individual item. The parent logic app would then use the workflow action type in order to invoke a run of the child logic app each of your repeat items.

Your parent workflow would then be defined as

```
"actions": {
  "http": {
    "type": "Http",
    "inputs": {
      "method": "GET",
      "uri": "https://example.com/pcme/3/7",
      "headers": {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Basic my auth"
      }
    },
    "conditions": []
  },
  "processEachItem" : {
    "type": "workflow",
    "inputs": { 
      "uri": <child flow direct invoke uri>,
      "apiVersion": "2015-02-01-preview",
      "trigger": {
          "name" : "runNow",
          "outputs": { "item": "@repeatItem()" }
        },
      "authentication": {
        "type" : " Basic",
        "username" : "myKey",
        "password" : "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      },
      "repeat": "@body('http')",
    }
  }
}
```

The following blog post explains the details on how to use nested workflows (how to obtain the direct invoke URI and configure authentication) and has a nice sample: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosag/2015/05/31/using-nested-azure-logic-apps-or-invoking-flows-from-another-logic-app/